# Перенаправление в htaccess на сайте

Tags: .htaccess

В htacces есть код:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|js|css|xml|txt|ico|jpeg|htm|html|jpg|png|gif|png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Код добавляем слэш в конце URL кроме определенных файлов.

Как сделать, чтобы это правило не работало для несуществующих страниц?

Сейчас при несуществующем url, например `sitename.com/blablabla` сервер отдает ответ 301 и делает перенаправление на `sitename.com/blablabla/`.

А нужно, чтобы при несуществующем url, например `sitename.com/blablabla` сервер сразу отдавал ответ 404 и чтобы не было перенаправления.

К сожалению я не разбираюсь в htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Добавить -f

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|js|css|xml|txt|ico|jpeg|htm|html|jpg|png|gif|png)$ -f
```